# How to get the account type of user in windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, user-accounts

I have a requirement to fetch the account type of the user (admin,standard user, guest). I have tried the NetUserGetInfo function which returns the USER_INFO structure only for local accounts. I need info for domain users as well. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Probably an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/205381). What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: i need to fetch the account type of the user (admin, standard or guest).

Comment: What are you going to do with that information? What sort of decisions are you going to base off of that data?

Comment: its the final requirement as of now!

Comment: @user3845075: that does not answer IInspectable's question. **WHY** do you need this information? "It is a requirement" is not a good reason. What exactly are you going to do with the information?  There is a reason it is not readably available.

Comment: @remy, frankly, i don't know! and why is it that it's not readably available?

Comment: Because that information is not useful for anything. At least I cannot think of a scenario, where this would be useful.

Comment: @user3845075: if you don't know why you have this requirement, then you have bad requirements. Get them clarified by whoever is giving them to you.  That being said, IInspectable is right. Unless you need this for display purposes, there really is no good reason to retrieve it.

Comment: You can use [`CheckTokenMembership()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376389.aspx) to check if a user is a guest or an admin. See [`AllocateAndInitializeSid()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375213.aspx) and [Well-Known SIDs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379649.aspx) for pre-defined SIDs you can check against.

Comment: While I agree that the requirement is dubious, there's nothing stopping you from using NetUserGetInfo for domain accounts.  Just feed in the name of a domain controller as the first argument.  (You can find a domain controller using DsGetDcName.)

Comment: @remy and IInspectable guys, even if its for display purposes, i am seeking help in retrieving that info. So ,is there a way to fetch that info?

Comment: @Harry Johnston, I tried that with dsgetdcname but the i always kept getting error 2221 (user not found) and sometimes there was just no output!

Comment: @RemyLebeau Isn't it different from group memebership? i mean to what groups does a standard user or a guest belong to?

Comment: @user3845075 see the links I posted. There are Guests and Admins groups you can check membership of.